# Proper way to set up a Trainer/Member relationship using one entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, entity-framework

I am modelling a Trainer/Member relationship on Ruby on Rails and I was wondering what is the best way to model this relationship.

Currently I only defined roles for a User class using Rolify for view and controller access.

Trainers and Members are users.

Should I do a recursive relation between the User model, or should I create a Trainer and a Member model specifically on Rails, and set up hierarchy between them, and create the relationship between the child models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would setup two different models for trainers and members as you proposed and use the rails association helpers.  For example, if a member can have several trainers and trainers can have many members you would want to implement a many-to-many relationship.  This is most easily done in rails via the "has_many :through" model helpers.  You can then add an attribute to these classes that would specify the levels of authorization or controller access on your app if need be.

Comment: I think it makes sense to have said models as you said mainly because there are functions from the Trainer that wouldn't make sense for the Member to have. However, if I go this route, will this justify the use of a gem like Rolify? I am currently using rolify to specify which user types can view which portions of a dashboard and I dont know if its wise to combine both approaches.

Comment: I am not familiar with Rolify but authorization is something that can be easily custom rolled if you're just looking to handle these two types.  For example, add a "before_action :some_custom_method" to the controller where that "some_custom_method" checks if the "current_user" is of that type.  If not it redirects them, flashes an error like you've probably seen in every rails tutorial ever lol, and returns false to stop further execution.